# Request code for permissions in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Please help me to get request code for permissions "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "WRITE_SETTINGS".
Also let me know source for request codes.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: You can define the request codes yourself.

Comment: how? can you give me a example

Comment: Just as a member in your `Activity` or `Fragment`: `private static final int YOUR_REQUEST_CODE_TO_DISTINGUISH_OF_OTHERS = 234;/* It could be any number */`

Comment: First, I would like to encourage you to edit your post, and tell us, what you done, what errors you got, show logs...etc --> . https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . After that, a fast search on google: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es

Comment: You can define the request codes yourself. Please give more specific problem description that which errors you faced.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple demo:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
              new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
              YourRequestCode);
}
```

You can set `YourRequestCode` any value,like `1`.

Comment: i was wrong about requestcode concept.thanks i this code done my issue.thanks to all..

Comment: It was that third parameter I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

[You can pass any integer value you want as the request code](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java).
The point of the request code is that you can distinguish between different permission requests in the `onRequestPermissionsResult` handler. The documentation example is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}
```

Here, `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS` is some constant variable containing the request code. The requesting line might look like this:

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1337;    
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                                   new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 
                                   MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS );
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the request code, I understand it is application specific, and see that you defined it, but I do not know what it would be used for or how it is helpful.

Comment: @Goku it's not well-explained in the documentation, they only mention that [you can also choose to not manage the request code yourself](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code). But I guess the use case is when you want to reuse the same class for handling these request results, but differently for different requests. I.e. if you had more cases in the `switch` in my example

Answer (score 2):

**FOR XAMARIN FORMS**
inject this code in MainActivity

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        string[] perm = new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteSettings, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage };
        RequestPermissions(perm, 1);
        Permission WESCheck = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
        Permission WSCheck = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.WriteSettings);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
    } else {
        uiBind();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_CONSTANT:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getPermission();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanations as well.