# FileNotFound, open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a file on external storage, this code was working fine 3 weeks ago, but from last 4 days it stopped working, i dont know whats wrong with it.

following is my code.

```
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "XXX");

//                log(exportDir.exists() + " ?????");
//                log(exportDir.mkdirs() + " ?????");

                if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                    exportDir.mkdirs();
                }


                File file_path = new File(exportDir, "backuptask.db");
                try {
                    file_path.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_path.toString());
                fos.write(array.toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
```

and following permissions set in the Manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

i have already asked for run-time permissions, and this code works fine for API >= 19, but throws following error in API < 19.

> /mnt/sdcard/XXX/backuptask.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>   11-13 17:20:47.776 4127-4158/com.XXX.XXX W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/XXX/backuptask.db: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 11-13 17:20:47.786
>   4127-4158/com.XXX.XXX W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>           at com.Tasks.exportimporttasks.TaskBackup.startBackup(TaskBackup.java:133)
>           at com.Tasks.demoimportexport.RestoreBackup$ExportDatabaseTask.doInBackground(RestoreBackup.java:272)
>           at com.Tasks.demoimportexport.RestoreBackup$ExportDatabaseTask.doInBackground(RestoreBackup.java:259)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>       Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>           at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>           at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
>           at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
>         ... 10 more

Comment: why not using run-time permission. try it https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: @evals thanks for your comment, i am sorry but i already mentioned in the description that i am already using run-time permissions.

Comment: maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540737/java-io-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-device