# My android application rejected for using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. How to fix it?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

My app targetting API 30. My app is integrated with `com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2` which uses InputStream & OutputStream to download & display file in pdfview.
Using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` to store downloaded files.
I have included these permission in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if I remove **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, my pdf doesn't gets loaded in android 10 & above.
If I include **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission google play rejecting my app.[image]
How to fix this issue. I'm stuck here no where I cannot find proper troubleshooting for this issue. Please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816379/8133524 check this

Comment: If i downgrade to API 29, I wont be able to upload app see minimum requirement. https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

Comment: You will not have access to `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`, except for documents that your app put there. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and let the user choose the document. You can then get streams from `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Can you share similar examples to Download & get file URL using ContentResolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried not to use `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` but instead used scoped storage which requires only

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Replaced this line

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

with this

```
 File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
```

App approved by Google Play also working fine.