# Android app rejected from Play Store - Issue: Access to device storage not required

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

> Android app getting rejected even after I've removed the Storage permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="r">
.
.
.
</application>
```

> Please suggest me, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139593/app-update-constantly-rejected-by-playstore-for-manage-external-storage-permissi

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb Yes, I've checked this post and removed code related to MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Even that Play Store give me "Issue found: Access to device storage not required" and "Please update your app so that the feature uses a privacy friendly alternative and remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.".